# How to fix warning in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm newbie in Rails. I did something and this warning appear:

```
warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby22, which recognizes
warning: 2.2.3-compliant syntax, but you are running 2.2.1. 
warning:please see https://github.com/whitequark/parser#compatibility-with-ruby-mri.
```

Can anyone help me explain why it appear and how to fix it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are running an older version of ruby. Try updating to [ruby-2.2.3](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/). You can use [RVM](https://rvm.io/) to manage ruby versions effectively.

Comment: Thanks. When I updated to ruby 2.2.3, I couldn't install 'bundle install' for example. It resolve my problem but I think if I do that, I need to install all again.

Comment: You need to run `gem install bundler` after upgrading `ruby`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got this error because I had the rubocop gem in my project which requires parser. I fixed it by locking my parser gem to the current ruby version we use.

For us, we use ruby 2.2.2, so I added `gem 'parser', '~> 2.2.2.5'` to my test group.

Since rubocop 0.24, he has used parser v2.2.x which means we we need to use ruby >= 2.2.2 to avoid that warning. Though the gem only requires ruby 1.9.3, so you can still use it but you're going to get warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I was seeing this not only for rubocop but also for rspec and so. Fixed it by updating the parser gem with bundler. Didn't really specify a gem version. Just the latest one.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using RuboCop, you may want to add `require: false` after the `gem 'rubocop'` statement in your `Gemfile`, so that you only load RuboCop when you use it.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading ruby to the newest version worked for me.

In my specific case I had

```
warning: parser/current is loading parser/ruby30, which recognizes warning: 3.0.1-compliant syntax, but you are running 3.0.0. warning: please see https://github.com/whitequark/parser#compatibility-with-ruby-mri.
```

and had to upgrade ruby from 3.0.0 to 3.0.1